# How to integrate ATOM Payment gateway in Android App

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I am working an android app and i want to integrate `ATOM Payment Gateway`
but Atom doesn't provide any mobile SDKs. so i am Totally confused how to integrate atom payment gateway in android..
i also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936546/how-do-i-integrate-atom-payment-gateway-in-my-android-app)

but there is only [php integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31131940/5722294)

No tutorials or examples in internet too.

Please help me

Comment: i think currently its available only for web based development

Comment: Check this...    I implemented this code and it works fine..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936546/how-do-i-integrate-atom-payment-gateway-in-my-android-app

Comment: @KinjalShah this question is already seen but there is asp.net and i am using php..

Comment: @nEwDeV you are talking about redirect url ? u can also do in php for redirect uri.. I have just used php code in redirect uri and now its working fine..

Comment: @KinjalShah yes dear how to put this `<script type="text/javascript">
 function showAndroidToast(reponseText) {
 Android.onResponse(reponseText);
 }` in php cade

Comment: @nEwDeV Put below code in php. It will work..                                 `<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<?php
$array = json_encode($_REQUEST);

?>
<input type='hidden' name='requestData' id='requestData' value='<?php echo $array;?>' />
<input type='button' name='data' id='data' value='click' onclick=showAndroidToast(); style='display:none' />
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( "#data" ).click();

function showAndroidToast(){
    var reponseText = jQuery('#requestData').val();
    Android.onResponse(reponseText); 
}
</script>`

Comment: @KinjalShah thanks i,ll try this code

Comment: @KinjalShah  this is given `"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"`