# Atom payment gateway not redirect bank website page

Tags: android, payment-gateway

hey i am using Atom payment gateway give bank detail after payment gatways page not redirecting and screen stay here [image]

and given error is

```
 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "[blocked] The page at 'https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/paynetz/ipg' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://www.example.com/url-return.php': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.
                                                                 ", source: https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/paynetz/ipg (1)
  I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[blocked] The page at 'https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/paynetz/ipg' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://www.example.com/url-return.php': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.
                                                                 ", source: https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/paynetz/ipg (0)
```

thanks please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Buddy ask them for new sdk named Libary_MobilePaymentSDK
use this code:-

```
WebSettings settings= webView.getSettings();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    webview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy where use this code in webview or confirm payment screen

Comment: @nEwDeV, try ur code inside this or declaire it inside onCreate . Plz accept this ans if you find this useful...

Comment: Hey Atom is providing sdk for Android @Laxmeena?  I also want to integrate atom payment gateway in android app.. can you help me ?

Comment: Thanks.. Please do.. currently I have referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936546/how-do-i-integrate-atom-payment-gateway-in-my-android-app this code.. but if atom is providing sdk then its better..

Comment: @KinjalShah, Please contact them , They are now providing SDK with demo code for android and i'm not sure about IOS right now .

Comment: looks promising, need to try this !!