# How to use ATOM payment sdk integration in android

Tags: android

I have to integrate ATOM payment SDK and I don't have any idea about this activity,there is no any tutorial regarding ATOM SDK integration

Comment: Try to check this link, it will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936546/how-do-i-integrate-the-atom-payment-gateway-in-my-app

Comment: Thanks Shane, I follow this link but I found some errors like XMParser parser = new XMLParser, getXmlFromUrl(vVender url), getXmlElement(url) and more things one javascript code and php code is also mention there where to place that code....??plz help

Comment: Prashant Das, Could you please explain how to integrate ATOM payment sdk in android application?