# How to pass the same value as Cash On Delivery to PayOnline in android

Tags: android

I have two radio group button (Cash on Delivery and PayOnline) when I click cash on delivery it passes all the related data of cart and customer detalis, but when i click to PayOnline it passes to another activity where it ask to fill the amount...??
I am using ATOM PAYMENT GATEWAY LIBRARY

### here is my code

```
    ActivityPayment.java
    package com.www.prashant;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.*;

    import com.atom.mobilepaymentsdk.PayActivity;

    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
    import java.io.IOException;


    /**
     * Created by Dev on 10/1/2015.
     */

    public class ActivityPaymentOption extends Fragment{

        private RadioGroup radioPaymentGroup;
        private RadioButton radioCOD,radioON;
        private Button placeOrder;
        private TextView textView;
        View view;
        ProgressDialog pdialog;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String getCustomerDataResult;
        String getCustomerDataResult2;
        String getCustomerDataResult3;
        String getCustomerDataResult4;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            Constants.lastDetails = true;
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_option, container, false);
            //Set Navigation mode as Statndard
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            view = v;

            radioPaymentGroup = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.radioPaymentMethod);

            placeOrder = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlaceOrder);
            radioCOD = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioCOD);
            radioON = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioON);
            //textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textShipping);

            placeOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                    int selectedId = radioPaymentGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                    // find the radiobutton by returned id
                    if(selectedId == radioCOD.getId()) {
                        radioCOD = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selectedId);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), radioCOD.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new getDataTask().execute();
                    } else if(selectedId == radioON.getId()) {
                        radioON = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selectedId);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), radioON.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent newPayIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MPSActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newPayIntent);





                    }
                }
            });

            return v;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    //            ProductsListFragment productsListFragment=new ProductsListFragment();
    //            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, productsListFragment, null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    //            getActivity().setTitle(Constants.Category_name.get(Constants.position - 1));
                MainActivity.getInstance().CallFragment(Constants.position);
            }
            return true;
        }





        public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                if (pdialog==null){
                    pdialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    pdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    pdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(getRetainInstance());
                    pdialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pdialog.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // parse json data from server in background
                shoppingCartShippingMethod();

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (pdialog.isShowing()){
                    pdialog.dismiss();
                    pdialog=null;
                }
                //textView.setText(getCustomerDataResult3);
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Result1:=> "+ getCustomerDataResult2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Result: "+ getCustomerDataResult4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (getCustomerDataResult4!=null){



                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Order Placed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else

                    Constants.OrderNo = Integer.parseInt(getCustomerDataResult4);
                OrderConfirmation orderConfirmation=new OrderConfirmation();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content,orderConfirmation,null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                getActivity().setTitle("Order");
            }
        }

        // method to set shopping Cart Shipping Method
        public void shoppingCartShippingMethod(){

            try {
                // add paramaters and values
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartShippingMethod");
                request.addProperty("sessionId", Constants.sessionId);
                request.addProperty("quoteId", Constants.cartId);
                request.addProperty("method", "flatrate_flatrate");

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                //Web method call
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
                //get the response
                String result = String.valueOf(envelope.getResponse());
                getCustomerDataResult2 = result.toString();

    //            // Call shopping Cart Payment Method
                if(getCustomerDataResult2.equals("true")){
                    shoppingCartPaymentMethod();
                }
                else {
                    getCustomerDataResult = "false";
                    return;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // method to set shopping Cart Payment Method
        public void shoppingCartPaymentMethod(){

            try {

                SoapObject PaymentMethodEntity = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartPaymentMethodEntity");

                PaymentMethodEntity.addProperty("method","cashondelivery");

                // add paramaters and values
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartPaymentMethod");
                request.addProperty("sessionId", Constants.sessionId);
                request.addProperty("quoteId", Constants.cartId);
                request.addProperty("method", PaymentMethodEntity);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                //Web method call
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
                //get the response
                String result = String.valueOf(envelope.getResponse());
                getCustomerDataResult3 = result.toString();

    //            // Call Place shopping Cart Order
                if(getCustomerDataResult3.equals("true")){
                    shoppingCartOrder();
                }
                else {
                    getCustomerDataResult = "false";
                    return;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // method to Place shopping Cart Order
        public void shoppingCartOrder(){

            try {
                // add paramaters and values
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartOrder");
                request.addProperty("sessionId", Constants.sessionId);
                request.addProperty("quoteId", Constants.cartId);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                //Web method call
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
                //get the response
                String result = String.valueOf(envelope.getResponse());
                getCustomerDataResult4 = result.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }



MPSACTIVITY.JAVA


package com.www.prashant;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.atom.mobilepaymentsdk.PayActivity;



public class MPSActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button payMerchantNB;
    TextView et_nb_amt;
    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    View v;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("In On Resume");
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
        et_nb_amt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_nb_amt);


        payMerchantNB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_payMerchantNB);
        payMerchantNB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                String amt = et_nb_amt.getText().toString();



                if (amt.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MPSActivity.this, "Please enter valid amount", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else {

                    Double doubleAmt = Double.valueOf(amt);
                    amt = doubleAmt.toString();


                    Intent newPayIntent = new Intent(MPSActivity.this, PayActivity.class);

                    newPayIntent.putExtra("merchantId", "1111");
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("txnscamt", "0"); //Fixed. Must be �0�
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("loginid", "1111");
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("password", "TEST@123");
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("prodid", "TEST");
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("txncurr", "INR"); //Fixed. Must be �INR�
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("clientcode", "007");
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("custacc", "100000036600");
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("amt", amt);//Should be 3 decimal number i.e 1.000
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("txnid", "013");
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("date", "25/08/2015 18:31:00");//Should be in same format
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("bankid", ""); //Should be valid bank id

                    //use below Production url only with Production "Library-MobilePaymentSDK", Located inside PROD folder
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("ru", "https://payment.atomtech.in/mobilesdk/param"); //ru FOR Production

                    //use below UAT url only with UAT "Library-MobilePaymentSDK", Located inside UAT folder
                    //newPayIntent.putExtra("ru", "https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/mobilesdk/param"); // FOR UAT (Testing)

                    //Optinal Parameters
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("customerName", "PRASHANT"); //Only for Name
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("customerEmailId", "prashantlaldas@gmail.com");//Only for Email ID
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("customerMobileNo", "xx85048450");//Only for Mobile Number
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("billingAddress", "Mumbai");//Only for Address
                    newPayIntent.putExtra("optionalUdf9", "OPTIONAL DATA 1");// Can pass any data

                    startActivityForResult(newPayIntent, 1);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed here it is 2
        System.out.println("RESULTCODE--->" + resultCode);
        System.out.println("REQUESTCODE--->" + requestCode);
        System.out.println("RESULT_OK--->" + RESULT_OK);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            System.out.println("---------INSIDE-------");

            if (data != null) {
                String message = data.getStringExtra("status");
                String[] resKey = data.getStringArrayExtra("responseKeyArray");
                String[] resValue = data.getStringArrayExtra("responseValueArray");

                if (resKey != null && resValue != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < resKey.length; i++)
                        System.out.println("  " + i + " resKey : " + resKey[i] + " resValue : " + resValue[i]);
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("RECEIVED BACK--->" + message);
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: plz help if anyone have idea regarding this

Comment: U r navigating to MPSActivity if its pay online check your code

Comment: what to do....? where to place that atom payment code..actually i have no idea

Comment: may i know your mail id or contact information

Comment: I think it will help you check [How do I integrate the ATOM payment gateway in my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936546/how-do-i-integrate-the-atom-payment-gateway-in-my-app)

Comment: in MPSActivity it passing all the merchant details